# How to clear a recyclerview on app start

Tags: android, camera

I'm new at android programming and I'm facing a bit of a problem. Watching some tutorials I started developing an app to open Camera, take photo and create an image gallery. All that I managed to build, except that I want it to renew (clear all items) of the image gallery on app opening (or any button click).

My MainActivity is:

```
    public class CamaraIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP = 0;
    private String mImageFileLocation = "";
    private String GALLERY_LOCATION = "RC Image Gallery";
    private File mGalleryFolder;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camara_intent);

        createImageGallery();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mGalleryFolder);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_camara_intent, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void takePhoto(View view) {
        Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
           photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

        startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            RecyclerView.Adapter newImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mGalleryFolder);
            mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(newImageAdapter, false);
        }
    }


    private void createImageGallery(){
        File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        mGalleryFolder = new File (storageDirectory, GALLERY_LOCATION);
        if(!mGalleryFolder.exists()){
            mGalleryFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg", mGalleryFolder);
        mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();

        return image;

    }


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private File imagesFile;

    public ImageAdapter(File folderFile){
        imagesFile = folderFile;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_images_relative_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        File imageFile = imagesFile.listFiles()[position];

        Glide.with(holder.getImageView().getContext()).load(imageFile).into(holder.getImageView());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesFile.listFiles().length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder (View view){
            super(view);

            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGalleryView);

        }

        public ImageView getImageView(){
            return imageView;
        }
    }}
```

activity_camara_intent:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take Photo"
    android:id="@+id/photoButton"
    android:onClick="takePhoto"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/galleryRecyclerView"
    android:layout_above="@id/photoButton"/>
```

Can anyone indicate me the way to solve this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can simply add another button signed to this method:

```
public void deleteContent(){
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "directory_name");
    if (directory.isDirectory())
    {
        String[] images = directory.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            new File(directory, images[i]).delete();
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after directory was cleaned.

Hope it's helpfull. Have a nice coding.

Comment: Hi Taras, thanks alot for the help!
I tried to set adapter but It's not working. The change I made was on onCreate section

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Do you know how to solve it? 
Thanks!